# Change Label's weight without affecting its size

Tags: python, tkinter

I am wondering if it is possible to change the weight of a Label widget (make it bold) without affecting its size at the same time. I want to use the default font, not a custom (named) one.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('150x150')

label = tk.Label(root, text='I am a pretty label')
label.pack(pady=50)

root.mainloop()
```

However, when I try to to make it bold, it seems that its size changes as well. I have tried the following:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('150x150')

label = tk.Label(root, text='I am a pretty label')
label.pack(pady=50)

font = tkFont.Font(font=label['font']).actual()
# print(font)

font['weight'] = 'bold'
# print(font)

label.configure(font=font)

root.mainloop()
```

...and this is what I get (it doesn't even look bold to me):

[GUI1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kis3N.png)

I have tried to `print(font)` before and after changing the weight and it seems that `size` is the same, even though it clearly looks bigger:

```
{'family': 'DejaVu Sans', 'size': 12, 'weight': 'normal', 'slant': 'roman', 'underline': 0, 'overstrike': 0} # before

{'family': 'DejaVu Sans', 'size': 12, 'weight': 'bold', 'slant': 'roman', 'underline': 0, 'overstrike': 0} # after
```

Another try:

```
label.configure(font='-weight bold')
```

...and I get this:

[GUI2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRgi1.png)

Is it possible to make the label bold without affecting its size?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not allowed to post more than 2 images, so here you can see how it looks when it's 'normal': http://i.imgur.com/edLYfpr.png

Comment: do `label = tk.Label(root, text='I am a pretty label', font=('bold'))`

Comment: I would guess that for most fonts, the answer is "no". Bold fonts are typically slightly larger than non-bold fonts.

Comment: That does not work for me. It does not retain its size, it becomes bigger. @SierraMountainTech

Comment: I guess I was misunderstanding your needs. It looks like Bryan has the short answer for you.

Comment: Well, if you say so, that must be it. It is a pity, though, I am a little bit disappointed. @BryanOakley

Comment: Why are you setting such a fixed size in the first place?

Comment: I'm... not sure what you mean. I have not set the size anywhere. @StefanPochmann

Comment: @mentalita Yes you have. Did you already forget your `root.geometry('150x150')`?

Comment: I'm... not sure what does that have to do with the fonts. @StefanPochmann

Comment: @mentalita Well, the window size and the font and the text and a few other things all have to do with each other in the sense that they must work together. You're using a combination that doesn't work. And what you're doing doesn't make sense. Setting that fixed size in my opinion is the problem, so I'm wondering why you're doing that.

Comment: You are not right, the label will look bigger even if the window is not of the fixed size. Try it and see. @StefanPochmann

Comment: @mentalita Not sure what you're saying. Yes, it's bigger, but why is that a problem for you? As far as I can see, your only problem is that the label isn't fully shown because you for no apparent reason insist on an inappropriately small window.

Comment: This is only a MCVE, and the problem with my real project is that there is no space for a label to become bigger since it completely ruins the rest of the layout. What you're saying does not make much sense, sorry. Nevertheless, I've got my answer.

Comment: What I said makes perfect sense. Although it really was a question. A question you now finally bothered to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a variable width font, most bold fonts are going to be wider than their non-bold counterpart. This has nothing to do with tkinter, that's just how fonts work. I think most fixed width fonts are the same size in bold and non-bold variants.

If you're relying on the default size of the label, the only way to do what you want is to pick a font family where the bold and normal fonts are the same width.

The other option is to use various options to make sure the label is large enough for the bold font, and laid out such that it won't change size when the text shrinks.

Here's a screenshot from a word processor to give an example of relative font sizes in bold and non-bold variants:

[image]

Comment: So, I guess I will have to find the right font to use. I appreciate your help, thank you very much, sir.