# Set label font to bold without changing its size and its font

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts

I know it's possible to use another object than `tk.Label` but I would want to do it with `tk.Label` (for various reasons, I'm not allowed to do it with another object).

What I don't understand is why do the font and the size of the label change when I just set it to bold. Here is a Minimum Reproducible Example:

```py
import tkinter as tk

# make a tkinter with two labels
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Login")
window.geometry("300x200")

label1 = tk.Label(window, text="Username")
label1.config(font="bold")
label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
label2 = tk.Label(window, text="Password")
label2.grid(row=1, column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Is there anyway to only change the label to bold and keeping its size and its font? I tried to get the font of label1 before setting it to bold so that maybe i could set the size and the font to what it was before setting it to bold, but I get that: `('font', 'font', 'Font', <string object: 'TkDefaultFont'>, 'bold')` and I don't really know what to do with it.

Comment: As an option: [fixed-width fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46306334/change-labels-weight-without-affecting-its-size).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@8349697](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8349697/8349697) I found the answer:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont

# make a tkinter with two labels
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Login")
window.geometry("300x200")

label1 = tk.Label(window, text="Username")
label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
font: dict[str, any] = tkFont.Font(font=label1['font']).actual()
label1.configure(font=(font['family'], font['size'], 'bold'))
label2 = tk.Label(window, text="Password")
label2.grid(row=1, column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can also [measure text width in pixels](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6.13/TkCmd/font.html#M10). For example: `f = tkFont.Font(font='TkDefaultFont');print("normal", f.measure("Username"));f.config(weight='bold');print("bold", f.measure("Username"))`